# Laurent series VS Fourier series.

Tags: fourier-series, laurent-series

Is there a link between Fourier and Laurent series ? Let for example $$f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_nz^n.$$
We have that the $a_n$ are given by $a_n:=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac{1}{2i\pi }\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz,$ where $\gamma $ is a close curved s.t. the inside contain $0$. In particular, if I set $z=e^{i\theta }$, then $$g(\theta )=f(e^{i\theta })=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}a_ne^{in\theta },$$
and thus look to be the Fourier series of a function $g$, and thus $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(\theta )e^{-in\theta }d\theta .$ I'm a little bit confuse... is there a strong link between those two series ?

Comment: @YuriyS: I edit my question

Comment: You have all the definitions on hand. Compare the two integrals. Nice observation, +1

Comment: @YuriyS: It's a z. I fixed it

Comment: Ok. Now as I said you can compare the two integrals, using the relationship between f and g

Answer (score 1):

See [Laurent Series Yield Fourier Series](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~rauch/555/laurentfourier.pdf) and [From Laurent to Fourier](http://zeta.math.utsa.edu/~gokhman/ftp/courses/notes/l2f.pdf).